# Android - How to save an array of int/bool, check if it exists, and load it back after restarting app

Tags: android, save, load, sharedpreferences, file-exists

Previously I've asked some questions regarding what method I should use to save some data from my app to retrieve at a later time after it's been closed/stopped.  I got the answers I was looking for, I think.  But since then, my efforts to implement such a feature has fallen way short.  I've researched various questions I've had, for which I thought I found answers.  But it seems that the answers, while maybe correct, are not a match necessarily for each other.  What I mean, is they might work separately, but coming from various sources, they don't work together as a whole, and for me they don't work at all.  I'm led to believe I want to use SharedPreferences.  That may or may not be the case, but that has been the direction of my efforts lately.

So I'll ask this multi-part question.

1. How would you go about saving an array of integers(or boolean values)?
2. Before loading that saved array, how would I check if it exists?
3. How would I load the array to use its values again?

Those are the basis of my issues right now.  Even at this point, as frustrated as I may be, I don't mind doing more research if someone can point me in the right direction, but everywhere I've looked seems to be missing information and I'm unable to really understand/see how to code what I want to do.

If you REALLY want to see some code, I can show you all my broken pieces at the moment (what I haven't deleted), but I don't see it doing you any good.  That said, I'll answer any questions you may need to help me out.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  The array will change very little from app version to version.  It should be about 500-2000 integers or boolean values (either/or will work the same for me). The array is basically a set of flags that tells the app to do one thing or another depending on the value.  The size will only change if I add or remove items between versions.  For this reason, after checking if the file/array exists, I'll compare the saved array with one in the app and act accordingly.

Comment: SAving for what purposes?  When do you want to reload them?  When, if ever, would you want to reset to defaults?  Are we talking arrays of 10, or arrays of 10 million?  Is the size static or can it change?  Your question is too generic to answer.  Depending on what you want SharedPreferences may be a good way to go or not.  It doesn't do arrays well.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response and questions, I'll update with hopefully all of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with data that has to be preserved through a reboot.  I found two ways to do it.

1) Data is seldom accessed.
Store data in .../files in some format that can be easily saved/retrieved.  I used JSONArrays to hold the data.  mContext.getFilesDir() will get you the path, and you can simply see if your file.exists() to determine if the data exists.
You will need to create an object that will:
1) convert your data to the stored format

```
for(int i = 0; i < mArray.size(); i++ )
{
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("THINGY", mArray[i]);

    ja.put(jo);
}
```

2) retrieve your data from the store

```
String js = readFromFile(fileName);
if( !js.isEmpty() )
        ja = new JSONArray( js );
for( int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++
{
//  CONVERT THIS ARRAY TO YOUR INT...
}
```

3) read/write files like this:

```
private void writeToFile(String fileName, String data) 
{
    try
    {

        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput( fileName, MODE_PRIVATE );
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        //  Log.d(TAG, "Writing output log...");
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();

        osw.close();
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create " + fileName );
    }
}


private String readFromFile(String fileName)
{

    String ret = "";

    try 
    {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(fileName);

        if ( inputStream != null ) 
        {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) 
            {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

JSON works well in this case because there are easy methods to convert to/from strings.

2) Frequent Access
I used SQLiteDatabase.  I use a Singlton and DBHelper.getInstance() to get access to it.  This seems like overkill, but it is a good solution if the amount of data you are saving is increasing beyond a simple array of Integers.

A really basic (but sound) place to start is: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html.  Note his page was written for 4.3.

HTH.

Comment: I've skimmed over this, and I'll definitely really look into it.  I've only seen the term JSON, and I always assumed it was just another programming language.  I really want to keep this as simple as possible (using methods which I can truly understand and appreciate).  That said, thank you very much for your response.  Like I said, I'll look into it for sure.